# How to define a homomorphism over $H^G$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, abelian-groups, group-homomorphism

In my lecture notes I have this exercise:

**Let $G$ and $H$ be cyclic groups. When is $Hom(G,H)<H^G$?**

In the solution, before analyzing if $Hom(G,H)$ is a subgroup they define the operation:

$\varphi \psi: G \rightarrow H: x \mapsto \varphi(x) \psi(x)$

and argue that with such an operation $H^G$ is a group . For this part they don't use the fact that the groups are cyclic at all.

Then they find that since H is cyclic, we can use the fact that it is abelian in order to have a subgroup, but argue that there is a weaker condition for that being cyclic, which I guess is just to be abelian.

My question is how could I have known that is the operation I need to define in order to have a group over $H^G$ and  that there is no other choice? If there are other choices, how do I know  that for any other choice of an operation, $Hom(G,H)$ is still a subgroup under the same condition(to be abelian for the most general one if I was right) found when using the suggested operation?

Comment: The “pointwise product” is a very common operation when you have the set of all functions from $X$ to a structured set $Y$. You know it from the real number (remember the product of functions in calculus? It’s that same product).

Comment: I think your thoughts are right, that the question is not well-defined unless the group operation is specified. That said, this is a very natural operation.

Comment: @ RghtHndSd ,  @Arturo Magidin, but are there other choices?

Comment: @J.C.VegaO: No natural ones; you can biject it with your favorite group and use [transport of structure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transport_of_structure?wprov=sfti1) to give it any number of group structures, but that is the “natural one.” In addition, it is very common in abstract algebra, as part of “general examples of groups”, to give the example of the group $H^X$ for an arbitrary group $H$ and an arbitrary set $X$ (it is equivalent to the direct product of $|X|$ copies of $H$). So it could be that the group structure is implicit in previous work.

Comment: @Arturo Magidin And for any operation I could came up with the subgroups stay  the same?

Comment: @J.C.VegaO: Of course not.  But since any other structure would be totally random, it is unreasonable to try to ask questions about them without specifying them. (Of course not because you can always give it a structure where the identity element is not even in the set that was a subgroup under a different structure).

Comment: @Arturo Magidin You are using the word "structure", while I am refering only to changing the operation but keeping it a group homomorphism. Since we are still in groups, the structure is unchanged. Correct me if I am wrong. So you are saying that changing the operation is changing the structure

Comment: @J.C.VegaO: The “group structure” consists of both the underlying set and the operation in question. If you change the operation, you change the group structure, even if you don’t change the underlying set. I’m not changing the set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First: I do not understand what “we can use the fact that it is abelian in order to have a subgroup” means. Do you mean, to prove that $\mathrm{Hom}(G,H)$ is a subgroup, or to just talk about subgroups? If the latter, that makes no sense to me. As soon as you have a group, you can have subgroups.

That said...

You may want to review any section in which they provide examples of groups, because the following is a common construction: if you have a group $G$, and a set $X$, then the set
$$G^X = \{f\colon X\to G\mid f\text{ is a function}\}$$
is a group under pointwise product, $(fg)(x) = f(x)g(x)$. This holds for *any* group $G$ and *any* set $X$ (you don’t even need $G$ to be abelian, let alone cyclic). It is, in fact, a special case of the direct product with coordinate-wise multiplication, as it corresponds to the direct product of $|X|$ copies of $G$, using $X$ as the index set. It is possible that your source or your lecturer already established this as the standard interpretation of the group $G^X$ whenever $G$ is a group and $X$ is a set. This includes the instance of $H^G$, by looking at $H$ as a group and $G$ as a set. So you should review your notes to see if this has already been discussed earlier.

While there are “other choices”, none are particularly natural. This is a standard construction; just like if somebody told you “take the group $\mathbb{Z}$”, you are expected to know we mean the group under the operation of the usual integer addition, even though you can give it all sorts of *other* group structures by using [transport of structure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transport_of_structure), it is unreasonable (almost perverse) to expect people to understand that “the group $\mathbb{Z}$” might refer to one of these many other group structures.

Now, because $\mathrm{Hom}(G,H)$ is certainly a sub**set** of $H^G$, we can ask whether it is a subgroup of $H^G$. It is here that you would use the fact that $H$ is abelian, because otherwise the pointwise product need not make the resulting *function* a *homomorphis*. Specifically, if $f$ and $g$ are homomorphisms, you would need
$$(fg)(xy) = f(xy)g(xy) = f(x)f(y)g(x)g(y)$$
to be equal to
$$\Bigl((fg)(x)\Bigr)\Bigl((fg)(y)\Bigr) = f(x)g(x)f(y)g(y).$$
The equality is equivalent to having $f(y)g(x) = g(x)f(y)$ for all $f,g\in\mathrm{Hom}(G,H)$ and all $x,y\in G$.

This will certainly hold if $H$ is abelian; though it may hold in other situations by happenstance (for example, if every homomorphic image of $G$ in $H$ commute with one another. For an extreme example, $\mathrm{Hom}(A_6,A_5)$ is trivial, because the only morphism from $A_6$ to $A_5$ is the trivial homomorphism, so here $\mathrm{Hom}(A_6,A_5)$ is a subgroup of $(A_5)^{A_6}$, even though $A_5$ is not abelian).

As to your final question: since there is no other natural structure to give $H^G$, there is no condition you can give.

Comment: The thing is that to prove Hom(G,H) is a homomorphism they take $\varphi\psi^-1(x_1x_2)=....=\varphi\psi^-1(x_1)\varphi\psi^-1(x_2)$ and for that they need commutativity in H, which I guess they get from the fact that every cyclic group is abelian, and then they argue that is should be sufficient to have a weaker condition for this, which I am almost sure it is just the abelianility

Comment: @J.C.VegaO They are using the fact that you can prove that a subset is a subgroup if you prove that it is nonempty and that whenever $x,y$ are in the subset, then $xy^{-1}$ is in the subset. Yes, the only thing they need is that the target, $H$, is abelian. You do not need $G$ and $H$ to be cyclic for that argument to go through. It is enough to assume that $H$ is abelian (and you don’t need to assume anything about $G$ at all.

Comment: @ Arturo Magidin You said X is a set, no other condition. If we use X as the index set, then this doesn't hold for  uncountable sets.

Comment: @J.C.VegaO: What makes you think so? It holds even if $X$ is an uncountable set.

Comment: @ Arturo Magidin I thought uncountable sets like $\mathbb{R}$ coudn't be used for indexing, since they cannot be numbered (ie they are not equinumerous to $\mathbb{N}$ )

Comment: @J.C.VegaO:  An index set does not have to be countable. Don’t know where you got that idea.